# How to fill text fields on the base of search result-MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to load data in textfields on the base of searched customer. I am working on 'create' customer view, where i have search field and customer input fields. Ajax Function which is suppose to pass parameter to action 'LoadCustomerInfo' and 'post' json data in textboxes

```
<input type="text" id="custm"/>(sutomer id)
<input type="button" value="search" id="btnSearchCus"/>
@Html.TextBox("CustomerName")
@Html.TextBox("FName")
@Html.TextBox("Phone")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearchCus").click(function () {
            var custm = $('#custm').val();
            $.ajax({
                cashe: 'false',
                type: "POST",
                data: { "custm": custm },
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadCustomerInfo", "Sales")',
                dataType: 'HTML',  // add this line
                "success": function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var vdata = data;
                        $("#CustomerName").val(vdata[0].Name);
                        $("#FName").val(vdata[0].FatherName);
                        $("#Phone").val(vdata[0].Phone1);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Create Controller although it has nothing to do with this for now,

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CustomerId = new SelectList(db.Customer, "CustomerId", "Name");
    ViewBag.SMClientBranchId = new SelectList(db.SMClientBranch, "SMClientBranchId", "Name");
    ViewBag.EngineNumber = new SelectList(db.Stock, "EngineNumber", "EngineNumber");
    return View();
}
```

Action Which Takes the parameter "custm" and perform actions is:

```
public ActionResult LoadCustomerInfo(string custm)
{
    var query = from c in db.Customer
    where c.NIC == custm
    select c;
    return Json(query);
}
```

The problem is, data not loading in textboxes, it seems i am doing some thing wrong...please help or any reference will be helpfull...Thanks For Your Time..

Comment: Why is your ajax `dataType: 'HTML'` whereas your `LoadCustomerInfo` action returns `Json`?

Comment: You returning `json` so it needs to be  `dataType: 'json',` And if you only need the first item, use `FirstOrDefault()` on your query rather that degrading performance by sending a lot of useless data across the wire

Comment: thanks for reply,,, yes data type: json,.i have made my whole day crap for this mistake... please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller method is returning `json` so you need to change the ajax parameter to

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  url: '@Url.Action("LoadCustomerInfo", "Sales")',
  dataType: 'json',  // change this
  "success": function (data) {
    ...
```

In addition you only need one object in the view, so rather than sending the whole collection, just return one object

```
public ActionResult LoadCustomerInfo(string custm)
{
  ....
  return Json(query.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data type should be `json`, not `html`, and you spelt `cache` incorrectly btw.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: 'false',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "custm": custm },
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadCustomerInfo", "Sales")',
    dataType: 'json',  // add this line
    "success": function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var vdata = data;
            $("#CustomerName").val(vdata[0].Name);
            $("#FName").val(vdata[0].FatherName);
            $("#Phone").val(vdata[0].Phone1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i alrady accepted from comments